# unfortunately, Location has stopped android

Tags: android

Here is my Code, why it is stopping? I wanted to try to get the GPS Data from the mobile phone?
The LocationListener is the Problem, i dont know wheres my mistake :/

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        text.setText("Bitte schlate deine GPS Funktion ein!");
        return;
    }
    String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    Location lastKnownLocation = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    if(lastKnownLocation != null) text.setText(""+lastKnownLocation);
    else {
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              text.setText(""+location);
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
          };
          text.setText("Wird gesucht...");
          locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`LocationListener` shouldn't block UI thread. Try to put it into different `Thread/Looper`

Look example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184318/android-gps-callback-off-ui-thread)

Answer (score 0):

please do the changes and it will work.

```
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

to

```
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```